# Cast string representation of Buffer into Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, buffer, converters

I want to convert a string that represents a Buffer into a string that is what the Buffer was encoding. For example, if I have the string

```
var str1 = "hello,there"
```

And then I convert it to a buffer using Buffer.from()

```
buf1 = Buffer.from(str1)
<Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 74 68 65 72 65>
```

Then if I take the String

```
str2 = "68656c6c6f2c7468657265"
```

And convert it back to give me EITHER the buffer again:

```
<Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 74 68 65 72 65>
```

OR simply just (since you can convert the buffer back to the string with .toString())

```
"hello,there"
```

Answer (score 1):

Buffer's [`toString` function](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) accepts an encoding type. In this case, use `"hex"`:

```
buf1.toString( "hello,there", "hex" ) // "68656c6c6f2c7468657265"
```

The [`Buffer.from` function](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) also accepts an encoding type as its second parameter:

```
Buffer.from( "68656c6c6f2c7468657265", "hex") // "hello,there"
```